# What would a covering system for $x^2+1$ primes look like?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

In trying to work on the question of whether there are infinite primes of form $x^2+1$, there's one issue I really don't get, and was hoping somebody might be good enough to help me out.

Most of my thinking on the issue starts with accepting the assertion that there are only finitely many $x^2+1$ primes, and then poking around the implications of that in hopes of finding something exploitable to disprove. (As an amateur, I know I might as well be playing the lottery, but hey.)

Finitely many $x^2+1$ primes implies there's some maximum $x^2+1$ which is prime. Thanks to Iwaniec, we know we at least get infinitely many semiprimes after that, but my impression is that we can't say much more concretely about their makeup and distribution. I reason that there can only be finitely many semiprimes of a $2p$ form, or $5p$, or actually any $kp$ for fixed integer $k$, since otherwise we could divide through by $k$ to get an infinite-prime polynomial.

I mention the above in case any of that is off track, but my main question is: do we have any concept of how such a covering system could exist, and what it would look like if it did? Since we can't cover infinitely many primes with a finite set, and we can't use any congruence tricks, I have absolutely no feel for this idea in general. It seems like it would require a never-ending stream of perfectly timed $4k+1$ primes falling into place, forever.

To clarify: I am asking for a little explanation of how a situation like this might arise, or maybe some useful keywords to search, or a link to a paper, whatever might help me wrap my head around it. Thanks.

Comment: we know primes that are $4j+3$ have to show up in even quantity in any factorization of the even $x$ valued ones. And that primes of form $4j+1$ have $-1$ as a quadratic residue so can divide the values directly without multiplicity considerations. We know that it's not the upper value in a  twin prime pair, as two less is always able to be factored partially. etc.

Comment: A cover set of $\ x^2+1\ $ is impossible. If we have arbitary primes $\ p_1,\cdots , p_k\ $ , take $\ x\ $ as their product to get a number which is not divisble by any of those. Not sure whether you mix the claim of infinite many semiprimes of the form $\ x^2+1\ $ with the infinite many primes of the form $\ a^2+b^4\ $. It is strongly conjectured that infinite many primes of the form $\ x^2+1\ $ exist, but all efforts to prove this failed.

Comment: If it has actually been proven that $\ x^2+1\ $ is either prime or semiprime for infinite many positive integers $\ x\ $, this would be a nice partial result. If you could give a link to this claim and/or the proof, this would be nice.

Comment: @Peter See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257082/the-sequence-n21-and-semiprimes for relevant links, including 1978 paper proving infinitely many $x^2+1$ semiprimes, which I suppose by default includes "infinitely many primes or semiprimes". And no, I was not referring to the $a^2+b^4$ result. Also, I may be using "cover set" incorrectly; if you mean finite set of primes, then yes, impossible; if not, then it is technically still open since this conjecture is frustratingly still unproven.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem